# Styling the submenu Image in uber menu wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Am trying to style the thumbnail image only for the submenu displayed in using the uber menu plugin, but I am unable to do so.

I want to style this class but styling it doesn't seem to work.

`<img class="um-img um-img-noresize">`

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: thanks..have tried `#um-img um-img-noresize {padding:10px;}`

Comment: `#xxx` is a CSS selector for an element with attribute `id='xxx'`, if you want to make a selector for the class, you'll have to use `.yyy` instead.

Comment: @t0mppa i tried .yyy but still didn't work

Comment: Works fine with me: http://jsfiddle.net/mzU5g/

Comment: Not sure, why its not working with my uber menu. Even with the element inspector this is not showing

Comment: Can you provide a link to your website (a bit.ly/tunyurl would work if you don't want to post the name of your site

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to style an id when it is a class. Try

```
.um-img um-img-noresize {padding:10px;}
```